# Remove object in array by id javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have two arrays like so:

```
const data = [
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634593915", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915"},
            {id: "1612634622462", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462"},
            {id: "1612634584081", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:04.081"},
        ]
    },
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634576145", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145"},
            {id: "1612634557111", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:37.110"}
        ]
    }
]
const listId = ['1612634622462', '1612634557111'];
```

Then I try to remove object in array by id in `listId`

```
const remove = data.map(re => {
    re.data.filter(item => {
        return !listId.includes(item.id);
    })
});
```

But when I log it out, I got `[undefined, undefined]`.

I want array return like so after remove:

```
const data = [
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634593915", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915"},
            {id: "1612634584081", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:04.081"},
        ]
    },
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634576145", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Can you help me. Thank you :))

Comment: Sometimes I don't get the need to post ton of answers if there are 1-2 good approaches already.. What good does it give to the community if the answers are pretty much the same?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634593915", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915"},
            {id: "1612634622462", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462"},
            {id: "1612634584081", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:04.081"},
        ]
    },
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634576145", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145"},
            {id: "1612634557111", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:37.110"}
            ]
        
    }
]
const listId = ['1612634622462', '1612634557111'];

const newData = data.map(item => {
  item.data = item.data.filter(item => !listId.includes(item.id))
  return item
})

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the result from `.map()`:

```js
const data = [
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634593915", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:13.915"},
            {id: "1612634622462", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:42.462"},
            {id: "1612634584081", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:03:04.081"},
        ]
    },
    {
        createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02",
        data: [
            {id: "1612634576145", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:56.145"},
            {id: "1612634557111", createOn: "2021-02-06T18:02:37.110"}
        ]
    }
]
const listId = ['1612634622462', '1612634557111'];

const remove = data.map(re => {
    re.data = re.data.filter(item => {
        return !listId.includes(item.id);
    });
    return re; // return here
});
console.log(remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that your inner `map()` function doesn't doesn't return a value - for each object in the `data` array. That's why is returned `undefined` for both iterations.
Also - If you `filter()` the array, you have to reassign it to itself to keep only filtered elements.

```
data.forEach(re => {
    re.data = re.data.filter(item => {
        return !listId.includes(item.id);
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know one more information. I just fix my filter func to run that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure not the best solution, but I would loop through each data object and filter the data array for each listId Object. Just like this:

```
data.forEach(element => {
  listId.forEach(removeId => {
    element.data = element.data.filter(e.id => e.id !== removeId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You need to check e.id, not e itself. as each element of data array is an object

Comment: You are absolutely correct did not see this